# Is “Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS + LAMP” production-ready?

Tags: server, security, lamp

Installing a **fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS** and then:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Is this configuration **production-ready** in terms of **security and stability**?

Comment: Define "production-ready in terms of security and stability".

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 2 things yourself.

- configure Apache to your personal requirements. Apache comes with a webpage that shows "ItWorks!" so you need to set up at least 1 virtual host in `./sites-enabled/`
- configure MySQL to your personal requirements. MySQL has no user databases so you need to set this up.

Both could be a problem regarding security: if you mess up the virtual host it is possible to exploit your machine.

But when it comes to this setup being secure and stable out of the box the answer is a plain "yes".

Answer (score 1):

No. Make sure to use `dist-upgrade` so that you get the latest kernel. And reboot after the kernel upgrade. Then set something up to continue to receive security updates and reboots after kernel updates, for example the `unattended-upgrades` package. For stability, you still need to add monitoring and backup solutions, as well as deployment reproducibility and upgrade testing.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your application and its usage will determine whether or not it is stable. If your application is more than simple website with a small memory requirement then you may need to tweak your apache2, mysql and php settings to get it stable e.g. increase php memory, apache2 processes, install a cache etc

Answer (score 0):

I did participate in a project where Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, LAMP and  Joomla was used. It's a solid environment but as any software, especially web-facing applications, you always need to **follow the security announcements** and download any **relevant patches**.

There is a mailing list for Ubuntu to receive security alerts and announcements:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce

And there is of course useful information on the sister site **Serverfault**:

Use the **tag** security and your choice, i.e. `[security] mysql` for questions relevant to Apache/MySQL.